# Create Buttons that Add 1 point and clear scores

Tags: java, button, counter

Trying to figure out how to code this properly in java.

```
Team1           Team2

0                10
(+1) (-1)         (+1) (-1)

     (CLEAR ALL SCORES)

(clear team1)         (clearteam2)
```

I have a variable for team1 and a variable for team2. When u click `+1` the score goes up 1 point, minus one decreases it 1 point unless the variable is set to 0.     A button to clear both variables and seperate buttons to clear one side or the other

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICFNk.png